# Python equivalant for a curl command on an IP based relay controller

Tags: python, http, curl

So I have an IP based relay controller that lets you turn the relays in it on and off using a curl command such as: `curl "http://192.168.1.100/current_state.xml?pw=admin&Relay1=1"`

How would I replicate this in python? I have attempted to use:
 `requests.get("http://192.168.1.100/current_state.xml?pw=admin&Relay1=1")
time.sleep(5)
resquests.get("http://192.168.1.100/current_state.xml?pw=admin&Relay1=1")
print("Complete")`

but it doesn't turn the relay on as it should.

Any pointers would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried printing the result? I know it's pretty straight forward but you didn't mention  trying it.

```
x = requests.get("http://192.168.1.100/current_state.xml?pw=admin&Relay1=1")
print(x.text)
```

Comment: I have a print statement afterwards that should trigger if the command goes through but it never does.

Comment: Thats the full code now snatchy, I don't know why but I tried running it again there and it worked fine? Relay turned on, stayed on for the 5 seconds and then switched off again. I dont know why it wasn't working orginally as I have not changed any of the code or the connection to the relay controller.